# Kafka Streams without Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-streams

I'm currently planning the architecture for an application that reads from a Kafka topic and after some conversion puts data to RabbitMq.
I'm kind new for Kafka Streams and they look a good choice for my task. But the problem is that Kafka server is hosted at another vendor's place, so I can't even install Cafka Connector to RabbitMq Sink plugin.

Is it possible to write Kafka steam application that doesn't have any Sink points, but just processes input stream? I can just push to RabbitMQ in foreach operations, but I'm not sure will Stream even work without a sink point.

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` is a Sink action, so to answer your question directly, no.

However, Kafka Streams should be limited to only Kafka Communication.

Kafka Connect can be installed and ran anywhere, if that is what you wanted to use... You can also use other Apache tools like Camel, Spark, NiFi, Flink, etc to write to RabbitMQ after consuming from Kafka, or write any application in a language of your choice. For example, the Spring Integration or Cloud Streams frameworks allows a single contract between many communication channels

Comment: Oh, maybe I got it wrong. 'cos I checked the Kafka Connect is installed to Kafka plugins folder (like this - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide)

I guess, can I build something like this chain:

Kafka Source (outside, covered by Kerberos) -> My Pipeline  Kafka Streams App (on my hosting) -> Kafka to Rabbit Sink (on my hosting) -> RabbinMQ (on my hosting)

The thing is Kafka Source is owned by another company, they provide only data and willn't let me install any plugins on their Kafka server

Comment: Kafka Connect comes with Kafka, yes, but that doesn't prevent you from running it elsewhere. You dont install Connect plugins on the broker

Comment: Does it mean like Standalone mode? It looks nice, but manual says it needs Confluent Platform or Apache Kafka downloaded and extracted (https://supergloo.com/kafka-connect/running-kafka-connect-standalone-vs-distributed-mode-examples/#Kafka_Connect_Distributed_Mode). Or it's just for scripts?